# Django AJAX requests: create and delete a course. deleting a course not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

In my app, I want to create and delete instances of Course using ajax. I have finished my create functionality, and it is as follows:

urls.py

```
app_name = 'courses'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('delete/<int:course_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from courses.models import Course
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    context = {
        'courses':Course.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        course = Course.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'], description=request.POST['description'])
        # return redirect('courses:index')
        # course is a queryset, we need to change it to a dictionary
        return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(course))
    else:
        return render(request, 'courses/index.html')

def delete(request, course_id):
    course = Course.objects.get(pk=course_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        course.delete()
        courses = Course.objects.all()

        return JsonResponse((courses))

        # return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(course))
    else:
        return render(request, 'courses/index.html', {'courses':Course.objects.all()})
```

here is the jquery for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.course_form').submit(function(event){
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                url: '/courses/create/',

      method: 'post',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $('.courses').append(`<p>Name: ${response.name},
                              Description: ${response.description}</p>
                              <form class="delete_form" action="/courses/delete/${response.id}/" method="post">

                                <input type="submit" value="delete">
                              </form>
                              `)

        $('.course_form')[0].reset();

      }
    });

  })
  $('delete_form').submit(function(event){
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/courses/delete/',
      method: 'post',
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

once I create a course, I append a delete button under it. the problem is that the forms are being created without a csrf token, but i dont know how to add one using jquery, given that the csrf token is python. any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: `url: '/courses/delete/',` requires `course_id` as parameter, it's missing

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options based on the Django docs about [CSRF Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request):

1. Set the CSRF token in Javascript via:

   ```
   {% csrf_token %}
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // using jQuery
   var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
   </script>
   ```
2. Get it from the `csrftoken` cookie and set it for all AJAX request:

   ```
   function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
     // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
     return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
   }

   $.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
       if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: I pasted both into my template and js file respectively, but no luck